# append PHP function to the_content

Tags: php, filters, the-content

I'm using the Jetpack plugin for related items and social sharing. Both of these options filter the_content and append themselves to the end of it. The problem is that I'm using custom navigation in my posts which I output by using this code above and after `the_content` in my `single.php`.

```
<div class="navigare">  
    <?php multipagebar(); ?>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <?php TA_content_jump(1); ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I know that to append something to the_content I can use a filter:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content)
{
    return 'text-to-append' . $content;
});
```

My question and problem is: how to append the navigation PHP functions so that they display before the related and social sharing items of Jetpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You will need to experiment with priority](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Parameters).

```
add_filter(
  'the_content', 
  function($content) {
      return 'text-to-append' . $content;
  },
  10 // this is a priority number; 10 is default
);
```

The "10" is the default priority. I don't know what number JetPack uses but your original code, without a priority, should run at "10" so I'd try "9", or "8". It should be possible to get your code to execute before JetPack's code.