# Information on plugin adding text when a post, page, or other such is displayed

Tags: plugin-development, the-content

I need to know what API a plugin would need to use to add text or HTML to the beginning or end of a posts's text when the post is displayed. I have searched on Google - but none of the leads I find have any relevance to the question I ask.

I need to know the API a plugin would need to use if it is to assure that the text of a post or page when *displayed* will have something *beyond* what is in the post's database contents.

Comment: You never came across [`the_content`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=the_content) while you were searching? That is probably the single most ubiquitous hook in the system.

Comment: Almost similar problem  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39918/wordpress-hooks-filters-insert-before-content-or-after-title

Comment: For example: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145619/21376

Comment: Well @s_ha_dum ---- at the time that I asked the question, I hadn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this filter to `functions.php` file. Make your changes as needed.

```
function display_my_content( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $the_content = 'Before your content';
        $the_content .= $content;
        $the_content .= 'After your content';
        return $the_content;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'display_my_content' );
```

WordPress theme API or plugin API can be used anywhere, so when you develop a plugin you can use the plugin API. All APIs can be found at [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_API%27s).